# SQLite SELECT not working in Ruby when used with regex capture string, but works with string literal

Tags: ruby, sqlite, irc

I am using the following regex to capture to match an IRC PART message:

```
:(?<nick>[a-zA-Z\d<\-\[\]\\^{}_]+)!(.+)@(.+) PART (?<chan>[#&][^\x07\x2C\s]{0,200}) :(.+)
```

It matches and captures the groups correctly, because when this code is run:

```
part_regex.match resp do |m|
    puts "#{m[:nick]} has parted."
    puts db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE nick = ?", m[:nick])
end
```

The first `puts` works, and outputs the correct string. But the second `puts` doesn't output anything. I know that the nick capture exists in the table. Whenever I use a literal string instead of `m[:nick]`, it works just fine. I am using the [sqlite3-ruby](http://rubygems.org/gems/sqlite3-ruby) Gem for manipulating the database.

Here is the full output whenever it receives a PART message:

```
>> :mark!~mark@Mark-Szymanskis-MacBook.local PART #testing :mark
mark has parted.
```

Comment: Try deleting the record instead of selecting it, and check the database if the record is deleted.

Comment: @user482594 That doesn't work, either.

Comment: I thought using #query would work, but it still doesn't.

Comment: Would whomever downvoted this please explain themselves?

Answer (score 1):

I decided on using string interpolation instead of placeholders.

```
 db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE nick = '#{SQLite3::Database.quote m[:nick]}'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Some database libraries, such as ActiveRecord allows SQL injection prevention using the "?" as a placeholder. I am not sure what database library you are using, but it may not support this type of string interpolation. Even if it does, it may still need to have the "?" surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: Surrounding the ? in single quotes gives me an error: `/Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:41:in 'bind_param': bind or column index out of range (SQLite3::RangeException)`. Also, I stated that I'm using the `sqlite-3` ruby library in my question.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure this isn't the case, since replacing the `m[:nick]` with a literal string works perfectly.

Comment: You may try explicitly casting the resulting object to a String via the "#to_s" method. It could be the class MatchData: m[:nick].to_s, or "#{m[:nick]}"

Comment: when putting the string directly into the query with `#{m[:nick]}`, it works. But I'd rather not have to do this to prevent SQL injection.